# File I/O sum each row of numbers with hasNextInt method

Tags: java

I need to write a program all in main that will go through a txt file and sum each row of numbers up using the hasNextInto method. I must use a while loop to read through the file and a for loop to sum each row and output each sum. 
Ex: 
Row 1: 10
Row 2: 15
Row 3: 30.
Here is what I have, but do not know where to start going from here.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Lab9_Problem1
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    int iVal;
    int iRow;
    int iRowSum;
    int iToken;

  iRowSum = 0;  
  iRow = 0;
    try
    {
      Scanner ifsInput = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/rconno7/Documents/COSC 236/9_1_Input.txt"));
      while(ifsInput.hasNextInt())
      {
      iVal = ifsInput.nextInt();

      }


    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException sMsg)
    {
      System.out.println("The file cannot be found or opened.");
    }


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a code that produces the necessary output for those interested or who may need something to go off of.

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class Lab9_Problem1
    {
      public static void main(String [] args)
      {
        int iVal;
        int iRow;
        int iRowSum;
        int iToken;


      iRowSum = 0;  
      iRow = 1;
        try
        {
          Scanner ifsInput = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/rconno7/Documents/COSC 236/9_1_Input.txt"));
          while(ifsInput.hasNextLine())
          {

         while(ifsInput.hasNextInt())
         {
          for(iToken = 0; iToken <= 3; iToken++)
          {
           iVal = ifsInput.nextInt();
           iRowSum = iRowSum + iVal;
          }
          System.out.println("Row " + iRow + " sum: " + iRowSum);
          iRowSum = 0;
          iRow++;
         }

          }


        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException sMsg)
        {
          System.out.println("The file cannot be found or opened.");
        }


      }
    }
```